# ReadWriteVariable list is empty in SSIS of script component

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence

The ReadWriteVariable list is empty in script component of SSIS. Please refer screenshot. What has to be done so that it lists package ReadWriteVariables

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally I found that you have to create your variables inside your package. This is how you do that:

1. Right click the blank area besides your Script Task.
2. Select Variables.
3. There will be a Variables Menu show up at the bottom.
4. Create your variables there.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create required variables then it will be automatically populate at ReadWriteVariable  field.

Follow this guide to create user defined variable.

Also pay attention for scope of variable.

[Create variables in SSIS](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-variables/)

[Reading and Writing to Variables in Script Task](http://www.programmersedge.com/post/2009/07/29/SSIS-Reading-and-Writing-to-Variables-in-Script-Task.aspx)

[How to use variables in a Script Task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/how-to-use-variables-in-script-task.html)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create an variable in your SSIS Package. Right click in open space  - Select Variables - Then go to variables window and add one. Then you will be able to see it in your readwritevariables.